# OpenCV with CUDA, very clear error message but unable to figure it out why?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu

I'm gonna start with showing the code that I was trying to test

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace gpu;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if( argc != 2){
        cout <<" Usage: blur_blur_blur.exe Image_File_To_Go" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    GpuMat img_gpu,dest_gpu;
    Mat img,dest; 
    img = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    img_gpu.upload(img);
    cv::gpu::Canny(img_gpu,dest_gpu,50,70); 
    dest_gpu.download(dest);
    imshow("picture",img);
    imshow("canny",dest);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it's just simple and easy code to practice and test OpenCV with CUDA. The problem is, I failed to run it. To be more specific, it builds but when I tried to run it error message pops up it says,

> OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (out of memory) in unknown function, file ......\sources\modules\core\src\gpumat.cpp, line 1415

the image I tried to processs was 1kb, resoultion of 54x33. It's actually smaller than any other thumbnail I've ever seen.

I have no idea where to look into. any help?

PS. I use OpenCV 2.4.7 with CUDA ToolKit 4.2 
    maybe my CUDA is too old for up to dated OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code worked fine for me without any modifications, using a 32-bit debug build.

System:

Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2012, CUDA 5.5, OpenCV 2.4.7 compiled with GPU support (Fermi target), running on a GTX 570.

Example input and output (resolution 640x480):

[image]
[image]

Comment: The system that I'm currently using is equipped with 9300GS, according to the GPU-Z it clearly has CUDA core on it. Now I'm trying to build the library with newer version of CUDA Tool Kit and SDK and hopefully, it's gonna be different.

Comment: Your GPU is very old and is unlikely to be supported by OpenCV. NVIDIA designates GPUs by their Compute Capability (CC). The 9300GS is a CC 1.1 device. Current devices are 3.0 and 3.5. In the CMake configuration for OpenCV, only Fermi (CC 2.0 and CC 2.1) and Kepler (CC 3.0 and CC 3.5) can be selected, so I don't think OpenCV supports anything older than CC 2.0.

Comment: With newer version of CUDA, now it's working. I guess it's some compatibility issue with the combination of each version of OpenCV and CUDA Tool kit.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory means that you don't have enough memory to allocate data. Solution is to run algorithm with smaller image or use another GPU.

It might also be that you are trying to debug instead of release. Make sure you are not building OpenCV with CUDA debug flags -g,-G, --debug.

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the post, the image was 1kb, resoultion of 54x33. I don't think image size is what matters here. and about the debug, I'm actually trying to build on release. (I didn't set any of the flags by the way.....) I just blew the whole code away after 'img_gpu.upload(img);' part and it still gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, probably you need to specify your `dst-buffer` before you call Canny as well.

Try:

```
dest_gpu = GpuMat(img_gpu.size(), img_gpu.type());
```

By the way you should be more specific. Which call rises the error?

Cheers